# Object required when trying to make variable Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Making a auto filter that relies on a range in another (I've named) in another sheet that can be applied by vba. I thought it was not over the top, but it keeps saying object required? if someone could help I would appreciate it :)

```
 Sub AutoFilter_Test()

Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngOrders As Range



Set wsO = Worksheets("CA Orders")
Set wsL = Worksheets("Kitt Codes")
Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("CritList")
vCrit = rngCrit.Value


rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Applications.Transpose(vCrit), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Try making the transpose into an array first, `arr = Application.Transpose(vCrit)` and then for the autofilter: `Criteria1:=arr`

Comment: Thanks Christofer Thats helped! unfortunately now its not finding anything with the filter and both ranges have got matching values. I have made sure they are both the same format but still nothing? any more advice? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Filter on Multiple Values (Strings)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilter_Test()
   
    Dim wsO As Worksheet: Set wsO = Worksheets("CA Orders")
    Dim wsL As Worksheet: Set wsL = Worksheets("Kitt Codes")
    Dim rngOrders As Range: Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rngCrit As Range: Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("CritList")
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rngCrit.Value ' assuming there is more than one cell.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim vCrit() As String: ReDim vCrit(0 To rCount * cCount - 1)
    Dim n As Long: n = -1
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Key = Data(r, c)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    Key = CStr(Key)
                    n = n + 1
                    vCrit(n) = Key
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Erase Data
    If n = -1 Then Exit Sub
    ReDim Preserve vCrit(0 To n)
    
    rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It works amazing to say the least and will help with a couple future projects aswell so thank you :)